# link open in a new tab using target = _blank on a tab that was previously opened as target = _blank

Tags: html

step 1:
from webpage on tab1, open up tab2 using a link on the page:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_BLANK">google</a>
```

step 2:
from webpage on tab2, try to open up tab3 using a link on the page:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_BLANK">google</a>
```

problem is step2 does not open up tab3 but instead loads the page back in tab2

tried this on IE and chrome

how can it be made so that step2 can open up in a new tab3?

thanks

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Wouldn't tab2 be google after step1? How do you open page from Google?

Comment: Perhaps `_BLANK` isn't the same thing as `_blank`.

Comment: please post code in it's entirety, because that description is very confusing.

Comment: @hobbs Good idea, but it doesn't appear they are case-sensitive. From the W3C, a link target is (in this context) "an ASCII **case-insensitive** match for one of: _blank, _self, _parent, or _top." http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#browsing-context-names

Comment: Just because it's supposed to be insensitive doesn't mean it is. Use `_blank`.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because browsers will typically look at your open tabs for duplicate targets that may be open already. If you add a dummy anchor to the end to make the target different (ie google.com#guid) you can hack around it.

Comment: so a new hacked unique link has to be dynamically generated for each page (e.g. google.com#guid)?

Comment: Correct, or it will refer you to the existing open tab.  I can see how my example was not extremely illustrative- updating.